# Как правильно создать 2Д игру, если не в Canvas

Tags: unity3d, canvas, unity3d-android

Не раз видел, как в комментариях или ответах к вопросам про проблемы с Canvas пишут

> Какого... у вас игра в Canvas'e

А как еще можно делать игру (2Д) если не в Canvas. Нет я конечно могу, например, вместо Image использовать Sprite Renderer и вытащить изображение из Канваса. Но тут 2 момента:

1. Как, например, вытащить текст? Он может быть только в Канвасе.
2. Если я размещаю GUI элементы (из которых и состоит все 2Д игра) вне Канваса (который регулирует изменения размеров объектов для разных разрешений экрана), то при изменении разрешения и размера экрана и соотношения его сторон все элементы вне канваса растягиваются. Получается, как сделать UI объекты и вообще всю состоящую из них 2Д игру вне Канваса?

Comment: 1) В чём конфликт того, что текст, хп бар и другой UI на канвасе, а игра на сцене, как в любой игре? 2) При изменении пропорций экрана  рендер сцены растягивается ЧТО? Откуда вы эту чушь взяли?

Comment: в доках написано 'Компонент Canvas представляет собой абстрактное пространство, в котором производится настройка и отрисовка UI. '

Comment: Ярослав, 1) А почему собственно все остальное не может быть в Canvas? если вся 2Д игра это и есть image'ы, text'ы, scroller'ы и т.д. 2) Какой еще рендер сцены? Я про это не писал. Я имел ввиду, что если я размещаю Image вне Canvas, то при изменении размеров экрана, например с AxA на BxB этот самый Image сильно растягивается и становится растянутым по вертикали и сплющенным по горизонтали, если это 2Д изображение человека, то получается какой-то худющий великан, или наоборот толстенный лилипут

Comment: Кстати, фраза "Все элементы вне канваса растягиваются" значит все 2Д объекты: текст, картинки, скроллеры, кнопки и т.д. Разумеется я не имею ввиду 3Д объъекты: куб, сфера и т.д., - потому что я спрашиваю про 2Д игру

Comment: наверное потому что канва в юнити не слишком быстрая, обычно для 2д все же используют основной рендер движок в паре с ортографической камерой

Comment: я бы даже сказал не "не слишком быстрая", а "слишком не быстрая".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы создаете проект, то Юнити спрашивает: 2D или 3D. Выбирайте 2D, тогда все графические ассеты будут импортироваться, как спрайты, камера по дефолту будет ортографическая и расположена так, чтобы вы видели только XY плоскость.

При создании игры в 2D используются `Sprite Renderer` для отрисовки объектов и свой физический движок с `Rigidbody2D`, различные `Collider2D` и тд.

**UI** элементы, такие как `Image` распологаются на `Canvas`, который по сути рендерится на другой камере, у него есть свой `Canvas Scaler` и `Raycaster`. UI в юнити очень тормознутый, построить на нем целую игру будет дорого, если, конечно, это не набор панелей и кнопок. Например, простенькая визуальная новелла: картинка, текст, кнопка далее. Если же нужны какие-то движения, то неизбежно снижение производительности, так как каждое изменение элемента помечает `Canvas`, как `Dirty` и перерисовывает его полностью. Изменение перентов в `Canvas` тоже отнимает кучу производительности. По сути UI в юнити уже находится в процессе замены на `UI Elements` как раз таки по причине своей низкой производительности.

Что касается `transform` в UI, то они там заменены на `RectTransform`, компонент, который позволяет настраивать отображение UI для различных разрешений. Вы столкнетесь с проблемами при банальных вычислениях координат объектов, так как даже если кастанете `RectTransform` в `Transform`, то получите разные координаты на разных разрешениях экрана. Можно конечно поставить `Render Mode: World Space`, но тогда будут свои проблемы.

Вывод такой: UI и Canvas не были задуманы, как система для реализации геймплея, не стоит использовать инструменты для того, для чего они не предназначены.

Что касается растяжений **UI** элементов: по всей видимости, неправильно настроены якоря, нужно разбираться с ними, простой способ поставить `preserve aspect` для `Image`. Если это происходит, когда вы вытаскиваете его из `Canvas`, то логично предположить, что перестает работать `Canvas Scaler`, поэтому всё едет. Но опять же, это всё относится к UI, а не к реализации геймплея.

Что касается первого вопроса: если это статический текст, подпись над объектом, то делаете его в графическом редакторе и кладете спрайтом на сцену в нужное место. Если это динамический текст, то кладете его на кенвас с `render mode: world space` и кладете его на сцену в нужное место. Если это UI, типа отображения очков, то размещаете его на Canvas для UI.

Comment: В UI пользуйтесь на здоровье, это же UI элемент. Как я написал выше, можно его использовать вместе с Canvas и render mode: world space и разместить на сцене, как просто надпись. Все зависит от конкретной цели. Но производительнее будет спрайт.

Comment: Окей, если используется просто абсолютно статический текст, то можно сделать картинкой (хотя для меня это как-то дико, но может привыкну), если текст динамический - использую render mode? если хочу менять из скрипта - то как обычно в Canvas. Но можно вопрос: можете объяснить чо такое render mode: world space, а то в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderMode.WorldSpace.html) не особо объянено

Comment: Этот режим располагает Canvas в World Space. То есть вы можете его располагать так же, как любой другой объект на сцене. И менять его скриптом вы тоже можете. Получается, что это UI элемент в пространстве сцены

Comment: А! Понял, это настройка в компоненте Canvas? а я почему-то подумал, что это надо гле-то в коде прописать. Ну тогда я все понял. И все таки, такие вещи, как например, ХП, голод и, например, энергия, в общем индикаторы мне следует распологать на Cnvas,верно?

Comment: . Да, все верно.